# Double Integration word problem

Tags: calculus, integration

In a certain metropolitan area, the population is approximated by the function:
$$P(x,t)=\frac{\ 7274e^{0.5t}}{1+x}$$

Where $x$ is the number of miles from the center of the city, and $t$ is the number of years after the year 2000. What is the average value of the population over the first $3$ years within a radius of $4$ miles from the city center? Round your answer to the nearest whole number.

I have mine being bounded from $-3$ to $3$ for $\operatorname dy$ and $-4$ to $4$ for $\operatorname dx$. Where am I making a mistake

Comment: Is this population or population density?

Comment: population i believe. I know I will have to divide whatever I get for my integral by the area

Comment: If the formula gives the population then the population is decreasing as the radius  is increasing. This seems to be nonsense.

Comment: @zoli Why is it nonsense that population would decrease as the distance from the center of a city increases?  That is typical.

Comment: OK. Then the formula gives the population density and not the population.

Answer (score 1):

The average of a function $f(x,y)$ over a rectangle $[a,b]\times[c,d]$ is given by

$$\frac{1}{b-a}\frac{1}{d-c}\int_a^b\int_c^d\,f(x,y)\,dy\,dx$$

Therefore, the average population over the first three years and within a radius of four miles is given by

$$\begin{align}
\frac1{12} \int_0^3\int_0^4 P(x,t)dx\,dt&=\frac1{12}\int_0^3\int_0^4\,7274\frac{e^{t/2}}{1+x}dx\,dt\\\\
&=\frac{7274}{12}\,\int_0^3\,e^{t/2}\,dt\,\int_0^4\,\frac{1}{1+x}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac{7274}{12}\,\left(2\left(e^{3/2}-1\right)(\log 5)\right)\\\\
&\approx. 6793
\end{align}$$

Comment: I don't understand the integral above. If $\frac c{1+x}$ is the population density then $c\frac {2\pi x}{1+x}dx$ is the number of people in a ring of width $dx$. So, should not the integral be $c\int_0^4 \frac {2\pi x}{1+x}dx$?

Comment: @zoli.  It isn't a population density.  It is the population.  And so we aren't integrating over a disk.  The integration was embedded in $P$ already.